# Obtaining non duplicate values from Access listbox column

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access 2016 I have a multi-select listbox with a single column :-

```
Item 1
Item 1
Item 2
item 3
Item 3
```

In VBA, is there a way that I can remove duplicates from selected rows and display the remaining values in a message box. So, the following values would be displayed from the data above (assuming all rows are selected) :-

```
Item 1
Item 2
item 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary and check for duplicates before adding new item

```
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For lngRow = 0 To ListBox.ListCount - 1
    If .Selected(lngRow) Then
        If Not dict.exists(ListBox.Column(0, lngRow)) Then
            x.Add ListBox.Column(0, lngRow), ""
        End If
Next

For Each x In dict.keys
    Str = Str & x & vbNewLine
Next
MsgBox Str
```

Comment: I am getting a "Method or data member not found" error on line "For Each x In ListBox.SelectedItem" with SelectedItem highlighted.

Comment: Sorry! i have not tested the code. made some correction to the code.